# SMTP mail server (sendgrid) error on submission

Tags: sockets, email, smtp, base64, sendgrid

I have an app that sends an email with image attachments thru an SMTP server (sendgrid).

When the application launches it initializes a Socket connection and authenticates the user(application. I see the following message returned from Sendgrid

```
SG ESMTP service ready at<foo..sendgrid.net
```

and I also get a successful authentication returned.

However, on sending an email I get the following 3 errors:

```
error 1 550  Unauthenticated senders not allowed
error 2 503 Must have sender before recipient
error 3 503 Must have valid receiver and originator
```

So this suggests to me that I must change the order of sender and recipient in my SMTP module. Internally I am taking an incoming ByteArray and converting to base64 string in order to send emails with attached files. 
So how would I change the following code excerpt?

```
        writeUTFBytes ("MAIL FROM: <"+pFrom+">\r\n");
        writeUTFBytes ("RCPT TO: <"+pDest+">\r\n");
        writeUTFBytes ("DATA\r\n");
        writeUTFBytes ("From: "+pFrom+"\r\n");
        writeUTFBytes ("To: "+pDest+"\r\n");
```

This is the entire class I am using. I call authenticate just once after the class is initialized and then sendAttachedMail when sending email with image attachments. And when testing using a local SMTP server WITHOUT authentication, everything works fine(emails and image attachments sent)

```
package org.bytearray.smtp.mailer
{
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    import org.bytearray.smtp.crypto.MD5;
    import org.bytearray.smtp.encoding.Base64;
    import org.bytearray.smtp.events.SMTPEvent;
    import org.bytearray.smtp.infos.SMTPInfos;

    public class SMTPMailer extends Socket 
    {
        private var sHost:String;
        private var buffer:Array = new Array();

        // regexp pattern
        private var reg:RegExp = /^\d{3}/img;

        // PNG, JPEG header values
        private static const PNG:Number = 0x89504E47;
        private static const JPEG:Number = 0xFFD8;

        // common SMTP server response codes
        // other codes could be added to add fonctionalities and more events
        private static const ACTION_OK:Number = 0xFA;
        private static const AUTHENTICATED:Number = 0xEB;
        private static const DISCONNECTED:Number = 0xDD;
        private static const READY:Number = 0xDC;
        private static const DATA:Number = 0x162;
        private static const BAD_SEQUENCE:Number = 0x1F7;

        public function SMTPMailer ( pHost:String, pPort:int) 
        {
            super ( pHost, pPort );         
            sHost = pHost;
            addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler,false,0,true);
        }

        public function reset():void{
            removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
        }

        /*
        * This method lets you authenticate, just pass a login and password
        */
        public function authenticate ( pLogin:String, pPass:String ):void
        {
            writeUTFBytes ("EHLO "+sHost+"\r\n");
            writeUTFBytes ("AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
            writeUTFBytes (Base64.encode64String (pLogin)+"\r\n");
            writeUTFBytes (Base64.encode64String (pPass)+"\r\n");
            flush();
        }

        /*
        * This method is used to send emails with attached files and HTML 
        * takes an incoming Bytearray and convert it to base64 string
        * for instance pass a JPEG ByteArray stream to get a picture attached in the mail ;)
        */
        public function sendAttachedMail ( pFrom:String, pDest:String, pSubject:String, pMess:String, pByteArray:ByteArray, pFileName:String ) :void
        {
            try {

                writeUTFBytes ("HELO "+sHost+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("MAIL FROM: <"+pFrom+">\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("RCPT TO: <"+pDest+">\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("DATA\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("From: "+pFrom+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("To: "+pDest+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Date : "+new Date().toString()+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Subject: "+pSubject+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n");

                var md5Boundary:String = MD5.hash ( String ( getTimer() ) );

                writeUTFBytes ("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=------------"+md5Boundary+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes("\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("--------------"+md5Boundary+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes("\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes (pMess+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("--------------"+md5Boundary+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ( readHeader (pByteArray, pFileName) );
                writeUTFBytes ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("\r\n");

                var base64String:String = Base64.encode64 ( pByteArray, true );

                writeUTFBytes ( base64String+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("--------------"+md5Boundary+"-\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes (".\r\n");
                flush();

            } catch ( pError:Error )
            {
                trace("Error : Socket error, please check the sendAttachedMail() method parameters");
                trace("Arguments : " + arguments );     
            }
        }

        /*
        * This method is used to send HTML emails
        * just pass the HTML string to pMess
        */
        public function sendHTMLMail ( pFrom:String, pDest:String, pSubject:String, pMess:String ):void
        {
            try 
            {           
                writeUTFBytes ("HELO "+sHost+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("MAIL FROM: <"+pFrom+">\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("RCPT TO: <"+pDest+">\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("DATA\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("From: "+pFrom+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("To: "+pDest+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Subject: "+pSubject+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes("\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes (pMess+"\r\n");
                writeUTFBytes (".\r\n");
                flush();

            } catch ( pError:Error )
            {   
                trace("Error : Socket error, please check the sendHTMLMail() method parameters");
                trace("Arguments : " + arguments ); 
            }
        }

        /*
        * This method automatically detects the header of the binary stream and returns appropriate headers (jpg, png)
        * classic application/octet-stream content type is added for different kind of files
        */
        private function readHeader ( pByteArray:ByteArray, pFileName:String ):String 
        {
            pByteArray.position = 0;

            var sOutput:String = null;

            if ( pByteArray.readUnsignedInt () == SMTPMailer.PNG ) 
            {
                sOutput = "Content-Type: image/png; name="+pFileName+"\r\n";
                sOutput += "Content-Disposition: attachment filename="+pFileName+"\r\n";
                return sOutput; 
            }

            pByteArray.position = 0;

            if ( pByteArray.readUnsignedShort() == SMTPMailer.JPEG ) 
            {
                sOutput = "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="+pFileName+"\r\n";
                sOutput += "Content-Disposition: attachment filename="+pFileName+"\r\n";
                return sOutput; 
            }

            sOutput = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="+pFileName+"\r\n";
            sOutput += "Content-Disposition: attachment filename="+pFileName+"\r\n";

            return sOutput;
        }

        // check SMTP response and dispatch proper events
        // Keep in mind SMTP servers can have different result messages the detection can be modified to match some specific SMTP servers
        private function socketDataHandler ( pEvt:ProgressEvent ):void
        {
            var response:String = pEvt.target.readUTFBytes ( pEvt.target.bytesAvailable );
            buffer.length = 0;
            var result:Array = reg.exec(response);

            while (result != null)
            {   
                buffer.push (result[0]);
                result = reg.exec(response);
            }

            var smtpReturn:Number = buffer[buffer.length-1];
            var smtpInfos:SMTPInfos = new SMTPInfos ( smtpReturn, response );

            if ( smtpReturn == SMTPMailer.READY ) 
                dispatchEvent ( new SMTPEvent ( SMTPEvent.CONNECTED, smtpInfos ) );

            else if ( smtpReturn == SMTPMailer.ACTION_OK && (response.toLowerCase().indexOf ("queued") != -1 || response.toLowerCase().indexOf ("accepted") != -1 ||
                    response.toLowerCase().indexOf ("qp") != -1) ) dispatchEvent ( new SMTPEvent ( SMTPEvent.MAIL_SENT, smtpInfos ) );
            else if ( smtpReturn == SMTPMailer.AUTHENTICATED ) 
                dispatchEvent ( new SMTPEvent ( SMTPEvent.AUTHENTICATED, smtpInfos ) );
            else if ( smtpReturn == SMTPMailer.DISCONNECTED ) 
                dispatchEvent ( new SMTPEvent ( SMTPEvent.DISCONNECTED, smtpInfos ) );
            else if ( smtpReturn == SMTPMailer.BAD_SEQUENCE ) 
                dispatchEvent ( new SMTPEvent ( SMTPEvent.BAD_SEQUENCE, smtpInfos ) );
            else if ( smtpReturn != SMTPMailer.DATA ) 
                dispatchEvent ( new SMTPEvent ( SMTPEvent.MAIL_ERROR, smtpInfos ) );    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note I am using this SMTP library...http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27 https://code.google.com/archive/p/smtpmailer/downloads If you can get it to work with SendGrid and provide the answer I will reward +500

Answer (score 0):

> So this suggests to me that I must change the order of sender and recipient in my SMTP module.

The order of your commands is correct. Instead, you should look at the first error message for the real cause of the problem:

```
 error 1 550  Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

This tells you that the [server requires authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication) from the sender, i.e. use of the SMTP `AUTH` command with user credentials. Attempts to send mail from an unauthenticated sender will be rejected.  As such, if `MAIL FROM` fails, then `RCPT TO` fails.  If `RCPT TO` fails, then `DATA` fails.  And so on.

Use the SMTP `EHLO` command to discover the `AUTH` schemes (and other capabilities) that the server supports, and then send the appropriate `AUTH` command before sending `MAIL FROM`.

Comment: yes I know but when my application launches I can see successful authentication. It is an XML socket connection. Since there is a single user(application) to authenticate should I have to reauthenticate each and every time I send an email? My assumption is that the first error message was directly related to the 2nd & 3rd errors, ie if I change the recipient, sender order correctly error1 should disappear.

Comment: @eco_bach: SMTP authentication is done for each SMTP connection (i.e. TCP connection).  From  the code you show I cannot see any authentication at all. And I also don't know what you mean with "XML socket", SMTP requires a TCP socket. Maybe you should show some more code, especially the initial connection to the SMTP server and how you successfully authenticate against the SMTP server.

Comment: Using this library http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27 https://code.google.com/archive/p/smtpmailer/downloads Editing my initial post

Comment: @eco_bach: your code shows no error checking at all. And while it implements an authentication function I cannot see it called nor can I see the result, i.e. authentication successful or not. I cannot even see that you get the responses from the SMTP server at all, i.e. you just seem to write and never check responses. Missing a proper trace of the SMTP session (i.e. what you send, what you get) I assume that you either don't authenticate at all or that the authentication failed.

Comment: this is the primary logic, not the complete application code. authenticate and sendAttachedMail are  called from another class where I also have my listeners set up

Comment: @eco_bach: so do you have a trace of the SMTP connection which shows the successful authentication or not?

Comment: Yes. this is my handler myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.AUTHENTICATED, onAuthSuccess); and I definitely see a response in onAuthSuccess Wondering if simply changing my port to 587 from 25 will make any difference

Comment: @eco_bach: I'm not sure what your code really does. For me it looks like that you are writing directly to the client but that you use some parser to interpret the responses. This means that the parser does not know which command the response is for and might misinterpret the response. Don't you have a really trace where both commands and the matching responses are visible? Maybe a packet capture? I doubt that the server is first accepting the authentication but then claims that the sender is not authorized. Apart from that an EHLO/HELO usually belongs at the beginning of the connection only.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: sorry, I had not examined your class carefully. You already have an authenticate method and it does what it should. So, apparently, while you think that you're calling it, either it isn't getting called, or it fails.

So check carefully that *the connection you're authenticating in* and *the connection you're sending mail in* are actually **the same connection**, and you are not maybe unwittingly re-creating a new, unauthenticated connection.

Also, you really need to check the results of the operations you conduct - in this case, the authentication. Is it really successful?

## Old answer

From your example and what little documentation I found, you need - or at least *appear* to need - **two** authentications. Probably [with the same username and password](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Troubleshooting/Account_Administration/help_i_cant_find_my_smtp_username_and_password.html).

The first one you're doing right, it is the 'XML socket connection' that gets you to the SMTP layer.

Now you need the second authentication. Otherwise all commands will fail and the errors will pancake one into the other, while the 'real' error, as Steffen Ulrich noticed, is the first.

```
writeUTFBytes ("HELO "+sHost+"\r\n");

// Inner authentication
writeUTFBytes ("AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
writeUTFBytes (Base64.encode64 (username) + "\r\n");
writeUTFBytes (Base64.encode64 (password) + "\r\n");
// HERE you really should read the stream and ensure it says 
// "Authentication OK" -- or something to that effect.

writeUTFBytes ("MAIL FROM: <"+pFrom+">\r\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

This line indicates the error:

```
error 1 550  Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

May it be that you have to register your sender email address in sendgrid first? See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Marketing_Campaigns/senders.html#-Create-Your-Sender-Identity

If you have already done this, what does the email activity page tells you? (See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/email_activity.html)